# dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, I cannot update my system. After the usual:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? `apt-get clean` and `apt-get -f install` did nothing.

Comment: Can you please  post the complete output.

Comment: I just updated the output.

Answer (score 7):

If it is in WSL, try (tks lifesaver.codes)

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.* /tmp/

sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libc-bin

sudo dpkg --purge libc-bin

sudo apt install libc-bin

sudo mv /tmp/libc-bin.* /var/lib/dpkg/info/
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in WSL. 2nd and 3rd commands failed saying that libc-bin was protected. What's also unexpected is that I can see those commands in my bash history but not in my terminal when I scrolled back to find the error messages.

Comment: @CharlieJoynt this should fix it.  `for PROBDIR in "" "/usr" "/usr/local"; do find "${PROBDIR}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" -type f -ls; done;`  and then follow above steps

Comment: Source: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4760#issuecomment-716390775

Answer (score 5):

Here the reason seemed to be a corrupted `/var/cache/ldconfig/aux-cache`.

The solution was to do (as root):

```
rm /var/cache/ldconfig/aux-cache
```

And afterwards execute

```
/sbin/ldconfig
```

Comment: This worked for me, although he second command did not exist for me.

Comment: I had to run `/sbin/ldconfig.real` on Ubuntu 20.04 then the installation worked

Answer (score 3):

I used to have the same error here, I did the following command:

```
 sudo apt-get --reinstall install libc-bin
```

And it worked, it reinstalled the `libc-bin` package and solved the issue.

Hope it helps

Comment: @Vitor Abella </br>  I am getting the same error. But when I am runninng your solution, I am getting    > E: Internal Error, No file name for libc-bin:amd64

Comment: I get the same error as @Erdnase `No file name for libc-bin:amd64`

Comment: i get same error :(

Comment: I get the same error as well.

Comment: `E: Internal Error, No file name for libc-bin:amd64` when attempting this on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS running in WSL on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, it turned out to be limits related. This resolved it:

```
limit datasize 2000M
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `sudo rm /var/cache/ldconfig/aux-cache` and `sudo /sbin/ldconfig.real` on WSL Ubuntu 20.04 .

Comment: I get `Aborted (core dumped)` running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on WSL in Windows 10 and original problem remains, similar to OP.

Answer (score 0):

With `rm aux-cache` I got:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
Aborted (core dumped)
```

and only https://askubuntu.com/a/1411267/1423238 helps:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.* /tmp/

sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libc-bin

sudo dpkg --purge libc-bin

sudo apt install libc-bin

sudo mv /tmp/libc-bin.* /var/lib/dpkg/info/
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1233076)

Comment: This looks similar to [another answer to this same question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1411267/618745), but appears to be missing the first command? UPDATE: I realized that our links are actually to the same place & it was a markdown glitch hiding the first command.

Comment: dpkg didn't let me remove this in WLS Ubuntu 22.04 because it was an essential package, so I had to use dpkg --remove and --purge with "--force-depends --force-remove-protected,remove-essential". After that this solution worked otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar problem to the OP, albeit with a different error code:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3.8
...
Setting up libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Aborted (core dumped)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
...
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 installed libc-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
```

After trying many of the other answers to this question, I found further inspiration in the answer to [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4930543/5771128).

I fixed the `Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` error by manually creating the folder:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I then checked the `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` folder existed:

```
ll /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

After which the `dpkg` command worked:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
```